# Does pip install libpff-python complete all build steps?

Tags: python, installation, pip, package-managers

Build steps below are included in the GitHub wiki of libpff using the tar file download, but are these also needed for the Python binding libpff-python? Not sure how as there is no libpff file to cd into?

Build steps:

```
cd libpff
./synclibs.sh 
./autogen.sh 
./configure --enable-python
```

After pip install I cannot import pypff (not found), even though I see this module in site-packages.

Have also tried to pip install libpff-20180714.tar.gz but see error C1083:

```
Cannot open include file: 'libbfio_definitions.h'. Have already reinstalled Visual Studio 2017 and 2015.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the wheels windows and macOS for `libpff-python=20180714` for **python37** here:

https://github.com/thomaskuoch/libpff-python/tree/master/whl

Then juste do `pip install <the_file.whl>`

The issue is you need to install Visual Studio to compile the `tar.gz`. It may be not installed on a entreprise computer.